# How to call a cloud function which is an express app?

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire

I need to call a cloud function which itself is an express app via AngularFire. If I call a "normal" function like:

BACKEND

```
export const myTestFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { msg: data.coolMsg.toUpperCase(), date: new Date().getTime() };
});
```

FRONTEND-ANGULAR

```
callCloudFunction() {
      const callable = this.functions.httpsCallable('myTestFunction');
      const obs = callable({ coolMsg: 'Hello backend' });
      obs.subscribe(async res => {
           console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

The above function gets executed properly. Now if the function is an express app, I want to call a route inside it for example: api/v1/user/profile , which will return the user profile data.

BACKEND

```
// main is the entire express app which you access as api/v1/<your_route>
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

the express app is working properly. I have checked everything with postman.

So how should I call the route? is it possible or should I do it "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, you won't use the angularfire api to call your http function.
Use the `HttpClientModule`, inject the `HttpClient` service in your component constructor and call your function with an http request:

```js
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const url = `/api/v1/user/profile`;
    return this.http.get(url, { headers });
```

Do not forget to rewrite your routes in your firebase.json to map your app and your express server to the same origin:

```json
{
  "target": "app",
  "public": "/dist",
  "rewrites": [
     {
       "source": "/api/v1/**",  // ==> call cf for every request matching the source path
       "function": "api"
     }
  ]
}
```

To test it, use the firebase:emulator. It won't work with localhost using ng serve.

Comment: thankyou! This is the way I actually did it but wanted to know if angularFire had direct support for something like this. Either way thanks for your reply and Ill accept as a solution